# How to find UI automation element via UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId

Tags: c++, windows, automation, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I want to get a group element which is only identifyable by the UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId.

I got the AutomationId from Inspect.exe

So i wrote following function.

```cpp
IUIAutomationElement* FindBy_UIA_AID(std::wstring UID)
{
    IUIAutomationElement* pElement = nullptr;
    IUIAutomationCondition* condition = nullptr;
    
    VARIANT var{};
    var.bstrVal = SysAllocStringLen(UID.c_str(), UID.size());
    var.vt = VT_BSTR;

    hr = pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId, var, &condition);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Error Creating Condition\n";
        return nullptr;
    }

    hr = MainElement->FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, condition, &pElement);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Error Finding First Occurence\n";
        condition->Release();
        return nullptr;
    }

    condition->Release();
    SysFreeString(var.bstrVal);
    return pElement;
}
```

but this always return nullptr (but without error). So i looked at Inspect.exe to check if the group is a descendants of my MainElement, which it is. I also wrote another function before which absolutley works fine.

The function does the exact same just searching by UIA_LegacyIAccessibleNamePropertyId.
This works and the element found is in same treescope as the element im looking for with .

```cpp
IUIAutomationElement* FindBy_UIA_NPI(std::wstring name)
{
    IUIAutomationElement* pElement = nullptr;
    IUIAutomationCondition* condition = nullptr;

    VARIANT var{};
    var.bstrVal = SysAllocStringLen(name.c_str(), name.size());
    var.vt = VT_BSTR;

    hr = pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_LegacyIAccessibleNamePropertyId, var, &condition);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Error Creating Condition\n";
        return nullptr;
    }

    hr = MainElement->FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, condition, &pElement);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Error Finding First Occurence\n";
        condition->Release();
        return nullptr;
    }

    SysFreeString(var.bstrVal);
    condition->Release();

    return pElement;
}
```

So now i wonder where the issue could be or how to get an element by UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId in another way.

Note. Both of the previous functions are member functions and the class has following valid members

```cpp
HRESULT hr{};
HWND hwnd{};
IUIAutomation* pAutomation{};
IUIAutomationElement* MainElement{};
```

**EDIT**: After manually looping through every descendant of MainElement I found out that many elements have no AutomationID even though in Inspect.exe they do, which is quite weird. Maybe someone knows why this is and how to fix this

Comment: UIA_LegacyIAccessibleNamePropertyId (30092) just doesn't reference the same property as UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId (30011). Not all elements have Automation Id valid value.

Comment: @SimonMourier I know that, in the example that was working I get the Element via name and in the other function I wanted to do the same but with AutomationID (which works partly). The issue im having as i pointed out in the edit, is the mismatch between Inspect.exe and IUI-API in regards to AutomationID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I discovered that the issue was with the Inspect.exe tool itself. I had accidentally left it in `Raw View` mode, which was causing it to show the  `Raw Tree` instead of the `Actual Tree` which is used by the UI Automation API.

The element i was looking for was not a `Control Element` so there is no point in trying to search with `FindAll` as the `IUIAutomationElement::IsControlElement` property is set to `FALSE`.

To fix the issue, one can either change the mode to `Control View` or use "IUIAutomationTreeWalker".

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-treeoverview) is also worth taking a look at.